# "A record" pointing at incorrect website

Tags: web-hosting

I am helping my debate club fix their website.

I believe that ownership of the domain lapsed. The website configuration and account are on bluehost.com, but according to this whois:

http://www.whois.com/whois/daldebate.org

Some Japanese company called GMO owns the registrar, or A record or something. (I'm not well versed with how this works). Bluehost tech support couldn't help me other than saying to contact GMO.

They don't appear to have any viable contact information; they have a webform but I didn't get a response through that.

I don't even need the domain to display anything useful right now, I just need it to stop displaying Japanese hormone stuff.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The domain name is not yours and belongs to someone else. You have no control over what happens to it now.

You can contact the site owner using the e-mail address found in the whois record, however, I warn you not to expect much. It sounds like this domain name is being monetized by a spammer. Spammers do not care what you think. It is all about cash.

Your best option is to create a new domain name and set it up to auto-renew so that there are no future problems. If it is a club, you can set-up a bank account for the club, put a few bucks in to cover costs, and use PayPal or other mechanism to pay the bill automatically. Same with hosting.

Comment: We own the domain name. I was just hypothesizing about what could've happened, but the bluehost account says that we own the domain.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Oh! Good news!! Cheers! Be careful. I lost a few domain names years ago that ironically, I was going to drop the next year anyway. My choice was made for me so it was not such a big deal thankfully. Essentially, I have been through this already but did not care too much except that it made me mad that I goofed. ;-)